# Old account recovery

Tags: accounts

Is anyone able to help with recovering an old Stellar account? I have tried to recover the account at https://launch.stellar.org/#/recovery with a username and recovery code, but I get the following message:

> Recovery disabled. Your old network account has been already upgraded to the following new network account: GDDR################################################

I think this number is maybe the public key? I have no idea how to use this information now to recover my lumens?